# Trouble Installing PostgreSQL icacls

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I'm trying to install latest version of PostgreSQL and the install keeps running into the problem of

> Error running the Post-Install Step. Installation may not complete correctly. The data cluster initialization has failed.

I looked online and found a lot of solutions to the problem and I've tried most of them. However, I keep getting the same error, so I looked at the Install-Log and it say that Icacls doesn't exist, which seems new.

> Called IsVistaOrNewer()...
>
> > 'winmgmts' object initialized...
> >
> > Version:10.
> >
> > MajorVersion:10
>
> Ensuring we can write to the data directory (using icacls) to  CORPORATE\pjy002:
>
> > Executing batch file 'radC235D.bat'...
> >
> > 'icacls' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> >     operable program or batch file.

Some other important things.

- Downloading PostgreSQL on a virtual machine
- Am an administrator of said virtual machine or at least can get adminrights
- Using Windows 10
- Installing PostgresSQL 10.4

Comment: It looks as if you are running the installer as a domain user - try to run it with a local administrator account of that machine (not a domain account). I assume you are talking about the [EnterpriseDB installer](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads)? You might want to try the installer from [2ndQuandrang](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-installer/) maybe that works better with a domain account.

Comment: You can also try a manual installation using the ZIP binaries: See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4974170 or here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4256125

Comment: Cool, I'll try those things and see if they work.

Comment: I've tried the things you're talking about (except running it with an administrator account - need to get approval for that). 2ndquandrang seems to be getting close but I can't open up the application. I've tried the Manual installation but I keep getting the same error message.

Comment: Nowhere in the "manual installation" are you required to run `icacls` (which is a standard Windows command line tool - I am **very** surprised that it's not available on your computer)

Comment: Yeah, I'm surprised as well. I'm guessing its some sort of security setting because it works fine on my PC. Thanks for the help man

Comment: Hmm, as long as you don't want to create a service the "ZIP file" install should work for any user as that does not require any special privileges

Comment: Well, I finally got elevated rights and that did the trick. Only wasted a day or so.

Comment: You should add that as an answer and accept that answer, so that the question will be marked as resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure out the problem. Had to get elevated rights and then install it. Thanks to everyone that helped.